# Compile Eco templates to JavaScript `.js.eco`

Tags: docpad

`src/documents/templates/myfile.js.eco` don't result in a javascript source, with my templates compiled.

Like [docpad-plugin-client-jade](https://github.com/emirotin/docpad-plugin-client-jade), but to [ECO](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco), and allow me to compile my templates to JavaScript, and use them in my Backbone app.

Any ideia? what's the best way to do this.

(I can't use Grunt to do this)

thks

Meanwhile found this article: [Node.js, CoffeeScript and Eco Templates](http://blog.markstarkman.com/blog/2011/12/13/node-dot-js-coffeescript-eco-templates/)

---

I have made a [pull request](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-eco/pull/3/files) on this today.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you're on a JS file you already have JS in your hands, you don't need Eco, which allows you to put JS logic in HTML (and others that don't have vars by default).

Comment: To use has template: JST['suggestions/index'] in Backbone.View.extend's

 The idea is create a templates.js with all Eco templates compiled, and available by 'path/inside/src/'

Comment: Only for templates to the client-side. Can be identified by `.jst.eco` . This allow edit templates inside my documents / templates structure.